# jQuery CSS in different browsers

Tags: jquery, css

When I'm trying to use jQuery like this: $('#myDiv').css('left')

In chrome it returns 10% which is what I expected because I set the left value as 10%;

But in firefox it returns value in px? How can I always get the 10%?

Thanks

---

So I think to get same results from all browsers it's better to let it return offset values.

Comment: Could you post your css?

Comment: How do you set the `left` value?

Comment: I set it as $('#myDiv').css('left', '10%')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can get a consistent response from...

```
var position = $('#myDiv').position();
var left = position.left;
```

This may not be in % as you want, but will be the same in all browsers. You might want offset() rather than position, if you want the position relative to the parent container.

Comment: I just checked Firebugs "Computed" styles. Same same, just shows the pixels.